# How a callback is being passed in to a function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, functional-programming

I was given the following solution to an exercise:

```
var s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  var newArray = [];
  // Add your code below this line
  this.forEach(a => newArray.push(callback(a)));
  // Add your code above this line
  return newArray;
};

var new_s = s.myMap(function(item) {
  return item * 2;
});
```

the idea is to build your own replacement for `.map()` method.

My problem is to understand the callback part. So far my understand of a callback, is a funct that is passed into another function (as an arg) and is called after something else.

I cannot see where is another function being passed in as the callback in the solution, so I'm struggling to understand the exercise, mainly: `this.forEach(a => newArray.push(callback(a)));`

Is there anyone who could clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily visualize synchronous callbacks by replacing the call with the functions code itself.

In your function call, `callback` is equal to:

```
  function(item) {  return item * 2; }
```

If we insert that into this line:

```
  this.forEach(a => newArray.push(callback(a)));
```

we get:

```
  this.forEach(a => newArray.push(
     /*item = a*/
     /*return*/ a * 2;
   ));
```

Or in other words, for each `a` in the array, `a * 2` gets pushed to the `newArray`.

Comment: so this means that ```Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback)``` is expecting the return value of  ```var new_s = s.myMap(function(item)?```

Comment: Yes, if you call a function you get its return value back.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm still quite confused of how the return value of the callback funct is being passed into ```.push(callback(a))```